# Angular Typeahead filter from more than one field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a typeahead that filters based on a person's name. My person object has more fields than just name (at least `{name, surname}`) and I want the filter to work based in name and surname.

This is the current typeahead, based on `angular-ui-bootstrap`:

```
<input type="text" id="friendInput" placeholder="Friend's name"
 typeahead="friend for friend in friendsList | filter:{name:$viewValue}"
 typeahead-template-url="friendDropdown.html" ng-model="chosenFriend" />
```

I have tried editing the `filter` part of the `typeahead` attribute, but I guess I haven't found the right way. What would the right way be?

Answer (score -1):

you can just declare a filter in your scope and use it

```
<input type="text" id="friendInput" placeholder="Friend's name"
  typeahead="friend for friend in friendsList | filter:nameFilter"
  typeahead-template-url="friendDropdown.html" ng-model="chosenFriend" />
```

And in your controller declare

```
$scope.nameFilter = function(friend) {
    var regex = new RegExp('' + $scope.chosenFriend, 'i');
    return regex.test(friend.name) || regex.test(friend.surname); // test on both field
}
```